# Cannot write out the value of a key in an object, but I can console log it

Tags: react-native

I am doing some work in React Native, and currently I am going through an API to retrieve some data. I stored the data in my state and it looks like this

```
{
    "id": "847469",
    "name": "Allsvenskan",
    "tournamentFK": "11075",
    "gender": "male",
    "countryFK": "6",
    "startdate": "2017-03-31T22:00:00+00:00",
    "enddate": "2017-11-05T20:00:00+00:00",
    "n": "2",
    "ut": "2017-06-20T13:02:07+00:00",
    "country_name": "Sweden",
}
```

I have tried something like

```
return Object.keys(this.state.tournament).forEach(key => (
    <Text key={key}>
      {console.log(this.state.tournament[key])}
      {this.state.tournament[key]}
    </Text>
);
```

The console.log works perfectly. I can see every value of every key.
But, I cannot print it out. I can't see anything on my phone. It's nothing about the color either, because I can see other text.

Any clues?

Comment: Post the rest of the code for your component

Comment: `forEach` returns nothing. You need to use `map`: `return Object.keys(this.state.tournament).map( ... );`